# In Flutter How to align textfield to the top with rest of the column

Tags: flutter

This is how the columns are aligned.

[image]

The weight textfield needs to move up to align with the green column. It should maintain the same width.

Flutter code:

```
    Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.indigo,
                height: 50,
                child: const TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Weight',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                ),
              )),
          Expanded(
              flex: 3, child: Container(color: Colors.teal, height: 100)),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(children: [
                    Text("test1", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25)),
                    Text("test1")
                  ]),
                  Row(children: [Text("test2"), Text("test2")])
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this parameter (Row):

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
```

Answer (score 0):

In the top-level Row Widget, add crossAxisAlignment.start